# CALayer CABasicAnimation chaining

Tags: ios, calayer, cabasicanimation

I'm animating a CALayer's opacity-property with the following code:

Creating the animation in a method:

```
+ (CABasicAnimation *)fadeIn:(float)begin duration:(float)duration remove:(BOOL)remove{

    CABasicAnimation *fadeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnimation.additive = NO;
    fadeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = remove;
    fadeAnimation.beginTime = begin;
    fadeAnimation.duration = duration;
    fadeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;

    return fadeAnimation;
}
```

Adding the animation to the layer:

```
[overlayLayer addAnimation:[VideoComposerHelpers fadeIn:1.0 duration:0.5 remove:NO] forKey:nil];
```

This is working perfect. However, now I want to add another animation to the same layer, right after the first animation finished.

```
[overlayLayer addAnimation:[VideoComposerHelpers fadeOut:1.5 duration:0.5 remove:NO] forKey:nil]; // fadeOut is a method similar to fadeIn
```

What should happen is, the layer fades in with a duration of 0.5 and right after that, it fades out with a duration of 0.5.
This doesn't seem to work, though. Is it because the start point of the second animation is the same as the end point of the first one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `CAAnimationGroup` something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeIn  = [VideoComposerHelpers fadeIn:1.0 duration:0.5 remove:NO];
CABasicAnimation *fadeOut = [VideoComposerHelpers fadeOut:1.5 duration:0.5 remove:NO];

CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fadeIn, fadeOut, nil]];
group.duration = 2;
[overlayLayer addAnimation:group forKey:@"savingAnimation"];
```

Also I'm not sure if I get the right values vor start, end, duration of the animations (you should check them) :)).

Comment: Glad I could help, I hope that the person who down voted to come with the argument, maybe it is something wrong in my answer (anyway I just copy paste a piece of my running code and I adjusted to fit your needs) so basically it should be a good answer :))

Answer (score 1):

A CABasicAnimation can have a delegate. The delegate will be sent `animationDidStop:finished:`. Now you can ask for the next animation in the chain.

In your case, though, you don't even need that; just use an animation where `autoreverses` is YES.

(Oh, and do *not* mess with `removedOnCompletion` and `fillMode`; that's just wrong, and examples that use them are equally wrong. They are needed only in the middle complex grouped animations.)

Comment: Here is the section in my book about CABasicAnimation, and the next section tells you how to use it properly: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_cabasicanimation_and_its_inheritance

Comment: Don't know if this is really what I want. The goal is actually to add this fade-in/out multiple times over a period of time. I though, I can just add the cue-points as animations to the layer, but that doesn't seem to be the case